# What is the best build surface for PETG?

Tags: petg, build-surface

This question doesn't necessarily have one answer.  I'm looking for a build surface that doesn't tear up when removing the PETG print, but still holds the PETG down and keeps it from warping.  I am printing PETG with the z-height almost too high.  Higher causes the PETG not to stick and warp or even release during printing.  But, I still have trouble with PETG prints tearing my build surface.  I've tried PEI and black build surfaces that don't identify the material.  The build plate on my hot bed is glass.

Comment: don’t use the smooth PEI side,petg would destroy it,use the rough side or textured side instead.

Comment: @FromENG: If you can select the side of PEI that you use, I assume this means you are getting PEI without adhesive and having to apply adhesive yourself, or are you using another method to hold down the PEI?

Comment: i have a prusa mk3s the pei is double-sided (smooth/textured) and the sheet is magnetically attached to the y carriage.You can buy one magnetic rubber(the other side is glued to the y carriage) and then attch the pei to the rubber to make a removable surface.For me the textured pei works like a charm.

Comment: Yes,usually they just pop off when i bend the sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Removable steel spring sheet with PEI textured coatings**

I have been using textured PEI string sheet for most of my prints, just love it.
Prints attach so good but not hard to remove(with proper nozzole Z-offset).

If the prints are small and seems hard to remove,heating up the bed helps a lot.

Almost never used the smooth side, even with proper z-offset, it still damages the surface quite fast.

Here's the link i bought before:
[Removal Spring Steel Sheet Pre-Applied PEI+Magnetic Base](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32986940303.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.538d6082oJJeV2&algo_pvid=ccd18793-4fca-4145-9db1-f3eb08bcc758&algo_expid=ccd18793-4fca-4145-9db1-f3eb08bcc758-2&btsid=0b86d81916099484894512885e7935&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_)

This is my setup on a ender3pro:

[image: three layered setup]
[image: removable steel spring sheet]

Comment: @FromENG: Do you remove the spring steel from the holding magnet and flex the steel to help remove the PETG print?

Comment: Yes,but most time prints just came off when bed cooled down, no force applied.Sometimes (big prints) i need to bend to release.

Comment: The spring steel sheet must have a larger thermal coefficient mismatch with PETG than glass.

Comment: 8 degrees lower on the top surface when i measure the temp,so i always set bed temp 8 degrees higher than Tg of that particular petg's i'm printing with.